# Prove that the value function $u$ satisfies this system of linear equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, solution-verification, stopping-times

I was struggled with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668970/how-hz-colorblue-alpha-sum-y-p-z-y-hy-follows-from-markov-proper). Hopefully, @Saad helped me answer it. Luckily, I've just figured my own proof :). I hope that someone can verify it for me. Thank you so much for your help!

---

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a discrete-time Markov chain whose state space $V$ is finite. Suppose

- $\psi, \phi$ are functions from $V$ to $\mathbb R_+$.
- $E$ is an open subset of $V$.
- $\mathbb{E}_{x} := \mathbb{E} [ \cdot | X_0 = x]$ and $\mathbb{P}_{x} := \mathbb{P} [ \cdot | X_0 = x]$.

We define $(\tau, u)$ by

$$\begin{cases}
\tau &= \min \{k \in \mathbb N \mid X_k \in E \} \\
u (x) &= \mathbb E_x \left [\phi (X_{\tau}) \prod_{i=0}^{\tau-1} \psi(X_i) \right]
\end{cases}$$

with the usual convention that the empty product is $1$.

> **Theorem:** $$\left \{\begin{aligned} \forall x \in E: u(x) &= \phi(x) & (1) \\
> \forall x \in E^c: u(x) &= \psi(x) \sum_{y \in V} p_{x y} u (y) & (2)\end{aligned} \right.$$ where $p_{xy} = \mathbb P_x [X_1 = y]$.

---

**My attempt:**

We first verify $(1)$. Notice that conditional on $X_0 = x$, we have $x \in E$ implies $\tau = 0$. By convention, $\prod_{i=0}^{-1} \psi(X_i) = 1$, so $u (x) = \mathbb E_x [\phi (X_0)] = \mathbb E_x [\phi (x)] = \phi (x)$. Next we verify $(2)$. For $x \in E^c$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
u (x)
&=  \mathbb E_x \left [\phi (X_{\tau}) \prod_{i=0}^{\tau-1} \psi(X_i) \right] \\
&=  \sum _{k=0}^\infty \mathbb E_x \left [ \mathbf{1} {\{  \tau = k  \}}  \phi (X_{k}) \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(X_i) \right]  \\
&\overset{(3)}{=}  \sum _{k=1}^\infty \mathbb E_x \left [ \mathbf{1} {\{  \tau = k  \}}  \phi (X_{k}) \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(X_i) \right] \\
&\overset{(4)}{=}  \psi(x) \sum _{k=1}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots,x_k) \in V^{k}}  \mathbb E_x \left [ \mathbf{1} \left \{  \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_i, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right\} \phi (x_k) \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \psi(x_i) \right]  \\
&=   \psi(x) \sum _{k=1}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots,x_k) \in V^{k}}  \phi (x_k) \mathbb P_x \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_i, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right]  \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \psi(x_i) \\
&=  \psi(x) \sum _{k=1}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots,x_k) \in V^{k}}  \phi (x_k) \mathbb P_x \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_i, i = \overline{2,k} \end{aligned} \;\middle|\; X_1 = x_1\right]  \mathbb P_x [X_1 = x_1] \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \psi(x_i) \\
&\overset{(5)}{=}  \psi(x) \sum _{k=1}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots, x_k) \in V^{k} }  \phi (x_k) \mathbb P_{x_1} \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k-1  \\ X_i &= x_{i+1}, i = \overline{1,k-1} \end{aligned} \right]  p_{xx_1} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \psi(x_i) \\
&\overset{(6)}{=}  \psi(x) \sum _{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots, x_{k+1}) \in V^{k+1} }  \phi (x_{k+1}) \mathbb P_{x_1} \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_{i+1}, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right]  p_{xx_1} \prod_{i=1}^{k} \psi(x_i) \\
&\overset{(7)}{=}   \psi(x) \sum _{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{(x_0, \ldots, x_{k}) \in V^{k+1} }  \phi (x_{k}) \mathbb P_{x_0} \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_{i}, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right]  p_{xx_0} \prod_{i=1}^{k} \psi(x_{i-1}) \\
&\overset{(8)}{=}   \psi(x) \sum _{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{(x_0, \ldots, x_{k}) \in V^{k+1} }  \phi (x_{k}) \mathbb P_{x_0} \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_{i}, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right]  p_{xx_0} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(x_{i}) \\
&\overset{(9)}{=}   \psi(x) \sum_{y \in V} \sum _{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots, x_{k}) \in V^{k} }  \phi (x_{k}) \mathbb P_{y} \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_{i}, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right]  p_{xy} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(x_{i}) \\
&=  \psi(x) \sum_{y \in V} p_{xy}  \sum _{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{(x_1, \ldots, x_{k}) \in V^{k} }  \phi (x_{k}) \mathbb P_{y} \left [ \begin{aligned} \tau &= k  \\ X_i &= x_{i}, i = \overline{1,k} \end{aligned} \right]  \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(x_{i}) \\
&=  \psi(x) \sum_{y \in V} p_{xy}  \sum _{k=0}^\infty   \mathbb E_y \left [ \mathbf{1} {\{  \tau = k  \}}  \phi (X_{k}) \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(X_i) \right]   \\
&=  \psi(x) \sum_{y \in V} p_{xy}   \mathbb E_y \left [ \phi (X_{\tau}) \prod_{i=0}^{\tau-1} \psi(X_i) \right]   \\
&=  \psi(x) \sum_{y \in V} p_{xy}   u (y)  \\
\end{aligned}$$

where

$(3)$: Because $x \in E^c$, $\mathbb P_x [\tau = 0] = 0$.

$(4)$: $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(X_i) = \psi(X_0) \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \psi(X_i)$ and conditional on $X_0 = x$, $\psi(X_0) = \psi(x)$, which is a constant and can be put outside $\mathbb E_x$.

$(5)$: Markov property.

$(6)$: Instead of $1$, we start the summation from $0$. As such, $k$ is replaced by $k+1$.

$(7)$: We replace $(x_1, \ldots, x_{k+1})$ by $(x_0, \ldots, x_{k})$.

$(8)$: $ \prod_{i=1}^{k} \psi(x_{i-1}) =  \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \psi(x_{i})$.

$(9)$: We replace $x_0$ by $y$ and separate $\sum_{(x_0, \ldots, x_{k}) \in V^{k+1}}$ into $\sum_{y \in V} \sum_{(x_1, \ldots, x_{k}) \in V^{k}}$.

**Remark:** If we would like to have the constant discounted factor $a^{\tau}$ instead of the random discounted factor $\prod_{i=0}^{\tau-1} \psi(X_i)$, we can define the function $\psi$ by $\psi (x) = a$ for all $x \in V$.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but it could be simplified by considering conditional expections over $\mathscr{F}_1$.

Comment: Hi @Saad, what is $\mathscr{F}_1$? Btw, to get the constant discounted factor $a^{\tau}$ instead of the random discounted factor $\prod_{i=0}^{\tau-1} \psi(X_i)$, we can define the function $\psi$ by $\psi (x) = a$ for all $x \in V$. I'm very happy that this version also generalizes the previous one.

Comment: In this case, $\mathscr{F}_1$ is simply $σ(X_1)$, so there's no need to consider a sum as complicated as $\sum\limits_{(x_1,\cdots,x_{k+1})\in V^{k+1}}$.

Comment: I got it @Saad. Your help is a great support for me in doing my thesis. Honestly, there is only two remaining problems [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673782/let-x-t-be-a-continuous-time-markov-chain-and-tau-the-first-jump-time-co) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673527/how-to-get-mathbb-ea-tau-1-phix-tau-1-x-0-x-mathbb-ea-tau). I'm sure that you will see their strong connection with the question in this post. Because this is my thesis, I want to tackle them by myself. I hope that you can leave some references or directions so that I know where to deep into.

Comment: @Saad I'm looking for your suggestion, but please don't let my questions disturb your work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Saad answered my question with his comments, so I post them here to close this question.

---

> Your proof is correct, but it could be simplified by considering conditional expections over $\mathscr{F}_1$. In this case, $\mathscr{F}_1$ is simply $σ(X_1)$, so there's no need to consider a sum as complicated as $\sum\limits_{(x_1,\cdots,x_{k+1})\in V^{k+1}}$.